# Автозамена атрибута в теге с помощью редактора кода

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Хочу заменить в тегах `<img>` все атрибуты src на data-src, по всему проекту, но чтобы не затрагивались теги script, js-код и т.п. Хотя я сейчас подумал, что поиск по 'src="' затронет только теги `<script>` с src и потом, в принципе, не сложно вручную поменять. 
Возможно ли сделать это с помощью регулярного выражения? искал примеры, но они не подошли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример на ***PHP***

```
$string = '<img title="xd" src="test">'; // примерная строка
echo preg_replace('/img.*\K(src)/ui', 'data-src', $string);
```

***Вывод:***

> `<img title="xd" data-src="test">`

Comment: это не подойдет, но, возможно, кому-то поможет

Comment: @EugenGedroyc, а в какой программе хотите заменить?

Comment: в одной из них: Notepad++, brackets, Atom

Comment: @EugenGedroyc, заменял только что в Sublime Text и в Notepad++, все прекрасно работает, опишите вашу проблему, чем не подходит?

Comment: интересно как у вас поучилось использовать эту регулярку http://www.imageup.ru/img84/3084127/replaceregexp.jpg

Comment: @EugenGedroyc, зачем вы заменяете регулярку на регулярку?
http://www.imageup.ru/img48/3084136/bezymyannyjj.png

Comment: Спасибо! удивительно, но работает! я даже не предтавлял что так можно заменить то что в скобках